# Group and rank Powershell objects in the pipeline

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to rank objects in a group in the powerhell pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem "*.csv" | 
Select-object fullname, Length, @{N = "Environment"; E = {
    if ($_.fullname -like "*Dev*") {
        "DEV"
    }
    elseif ($_.fullname -like "*PROD*") {
        "PROD"
    }
    elseif ($_.fullname -like "*UAT*") {
        "UAT"
    }
}} | Sort-Object -Property Environment, Length
```

I would like to add the `Rank` property with a below value in the pipeline on the basis of group (Environment & Length). Is there anything in-built in powershell like [SQL ranking function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql)

```
FullName                               Length Environment Rank 
--------                               ------ ----------- ----
C:\Temp\ReportDEV-20171210_210653.csv    3065 DEV         1
C:\Temp\ReportDEV-20171210_211041.csv    9116 DEV         2
C:\Temp\ReportDEV-20171210_190100.csv   76286 DEV         3
C:\Temp\ReportDEV-20171210_200229.csv  511546 DEV         4
C:\Temp\ReportPROD-20171210_210349.csv   2835 PROD        1
C:\Temp\ReportPROD-20171210_210754.csv   8897 PROD        2
C:\Temp\ReportPROD-20171210_184729.csv  43850 PROD        3
C:\Temp\ReportPROD-20171210_191133.csv 213202 PROD        4
C:\Temp\ReportUAT-20171210_210554.csv    3065 UAT         1
C:\Temp\ReportUAT-20171210_210920.csv    9116 UAT         2
C:\Temp\ReportUAT-20171210_185308.csv   57244 UAT         3
C:\Temp\ReportUAT-20171210_193211.csv  306154 UAT         4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, PowerShell does *not* offer a ranking function out of the box, so additional work is needed:

```
$rank = 0
$prevEnv = ''
Get-ChildItem *.csv | Select-Object FullName, Length, @{ 
    n='Environment'; e={ $_.Name -replace '.*(DEV|PROD|UAT).*', '$1' } } |
  Sort-Object Environment, Length | Select-Object *, @{
      n='Rank'; e={
        ++$rank
        if ($prevEnv -ne $_.Environment) { 
          $rank = 1
          Set-Variable -Scope 1 prevEnv $_.Environment
        }
        Set-Variable -Scope 1 rank $rank
        $rank
    }
  }
```

<sup>Note the simplified approach to mapping the input filenames to environment names in the `.Environment` property, using `-replace` with a regular expression and a capture group to extract the token of interest from the filename.</sup>

- After adding the `.Environment` property via `Select-Object`, the objects are sorted by `.Environment` first, then by `.Length` (file size in bytes).
- The resulting objects are then given a `.Rank` property via another `Select-Object` call, whose value is a `1`-based sequence number that is reset whenever a  new `.Environment` value is encountered, effectively amounting to per-environment file-size ranking.
- Note the need for `Set-Variable` in order to modify the `$rank` and `$prevEnv` variables, because these variables must be maintained in the scope of the pipeline as a whole in order for them to persist across successive `Select-Object` invocations (by contrast, for instance, inside the script block assigned to key `e`, a local `$rank` variable would be scoped to that script block only).

---

Alternatively, use `Group-Object` (more concise, but less efficient):

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv | Select-Object FullName, Length, @{ 
    n='Environment'; e={ $_.Name -replace '.*(DEV|PROD|UAT).*', '$1' }
} |
    Group-Object Environment | ForEach-Object {
      $rank = 0
      $_.Group | Sort-Object Length | Select-Object *, @{ 
       n='Rank'; e={ Set-Variable -Scope 1 rank ($rank+1); $rank } 
      }
    }
```

- `Group-Object Environment` groups the input objects by the newly added `.Environment` property.
- `ForEach-Object` then loops over all resulting groups.

  - Each group's (`$_`) members are enumerated via the `.Group` property, and sorted by `.Length`.
  - A 2nd `Select-Object` call then loops over the length-sorted group members and produces augmented output objects that have a `.Rank` property reflecting the 1-based group-relative rank based on the file size (length) in ascending order.
  - Note the need for `Set-Variable` in order to increment the `$rank` variable, because that variable must be maintained at the level of the `ForEach-Object` body for it to exist across successive `Select-Object` invocations (inside the script block assigned to key `e`, a local `$rank` variable would be scoped to that script block only).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to add the rank to output object simply.

`ForEach-Object` accepts a script block as begin script in the first parameter. I use it to declare the counter and then the second parameter which is for process script, in addition to create the desired output object, I also incremented the counter.

**Example 1 - Row Number for Rows:**

```bsh
Get-ChildItem "C:\SomeDirectory" -Recurse -File | Sort-Object Name |
    ForEach-Object {$i = 1} {
        New-Object psObject -Property @{Name= $_.Name; Rank= $i++;}
}
```

*Result*

```
Name           Rank
----           ----
Product1-1.txt    1
Product1-2.txt    2
Product1-3.txt    3
Product2-1.txt    4
Product2-2.txt    5
```

**Example 2 - Row Number for Rows in Groups:**

```bsh
Get-ChildItem "C:\SomeDirectory" -Recurse -File | Group-Object DirectoryName | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | ForEach-Object {$i = 1} {
            New-Object psObject -Property @{
                 GroupName= $_.Directory.Name; Name= $_.Name;Rank= $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

*Result*

```
GroupName Name           Rank
--------- ----           ----
Category1 Product1-1.txt    1
Category1 Product1-2.txt    2
Category1 Product1-3.txt    3
Category2 Product2-1.txt    1
Category2 Product2-2.txt    2
```